# Getting the colors right for a gif

Tags: export, gif-format

When I'm exporting a list of images to a gif in Mathematica 9 I've encountered the problem that the colors are not obtained.

The images where made using `Show`, `ParametricPlot3D` and `Hue` as a constant plus some function depending on the two parameters. When I look at the list of images the colors are correct, but when I export it to a gif using `Export["path\\filename.gif", list_of_images]`, it's the brightness that changes instead of the hue. This problem has not been there with former gifs. I've moved to windows 10 recently.

There's a lot of code so I made some random toy example that gives the same problem:

```
animation = Table[Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u]*(Sin[R] + Sin[v]), 
  Sin[u]*(Sin[R] + Sin[v]), Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, 2*Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Hue[0.3 - u*Sin[R], 1, 1, 1]], 
 Mesh -> None, Axes -> None], ImageSize -> {400, 400}, 
Boxed -> False], {R, 0, Pi, Pi/20}];

Export["example.gif", animation, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity, "DisplayDurations" -> .05];
```

Can someone see where the problem is?

Comment: Can you please supply an example other people can try out?

Comment: Do you mean *Windows 10*?

Comment: Ok, I've added some code.

Comment: Feyre, you're right, I mean Windows 10. Corrected that in my initial question.

Comment: I tried it out on my machine - well I have Mathematica 10.4. It worked. Can you post a link to what results you get and possible what you are expecting. Here is what I am getting after running your code : 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwHd5YdfBGISSjRGb0R3b1dHY2c

Comment: Thank you, now I'm sure the problem lies in the software used to run the gif (Quicktime), which is supposed to support the format. When I upload it on the web it actually works. No big deal then.

Comment: @FidRewe Why run an image on a video player? I suggest running gifs on `IrfanView`.

Comment: you can also drag any gif into your favorite browser to show the animation (no need to make a web page)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a  Mathematica issue but an OS and external utility issue.